# How to read all files of a folder from different website with php?

Tags: php

How to read all files of a folder from different website with php?

i tried with this

```
$directory = "http://www.******.com/files/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.png");

//print each file name
foreach($images as $image)
{
  echo $image;
}
```

but not working

Comment: You cannot open a remote directly like that.

Comment: lol.  you can't glob across http..  the best you can do is cURL http://domain/files/ and hope that it provides a directory index, then you can get all files from this directory index and download them individually.

Comment: @KabirUddin It may be most beneficial to your profile for you to delete this question, then you will regain the lost points from a severely downvoted question.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP `glob` [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

> This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined
>   must be accessible via the server's filesystem.

If the remote site provides a directory listing, you can view a list of files from there. Otherwise, you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a grubber. Look all link on page and analyze them.